# Development Time for Arista EDU Ultra 200 rated at EI 200 in F76+

Tags: developing, developer, development

I am looking for the development time of Arista EDU Ultra 200 black and white film in F76+ developer when using an exposure index of 200.

The Massive Development Chart does not provide a recipe for this combination.

Comment: Doesn't F76+ use the same times as D76?

Comment: @ZeissIkon There is no consistent relationship between the developers. At Box Speed, in F76+ Ilford PanF+ is 5.5 minutes at 1:14 (a unique dilution). At box speed in D76 Ilford PanF+ is 6.5 minutes, 8 minutes, 15 minutes for stock, 1:1, 1:3

Comment: @ZeissIkon there is also no consistent relationship between dilutions. F76+ is typically 1:9 or 1:19 (except Ilford PanF+ as noted). Typical D76 dilutions are stock, 1:1, and 1:3.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Even more muddled is the D76 times for Arista EDU Ultra 200 at EI 200 are 5 to 6 minutes, 8 to 9 minutes, and 12 to 13 minutes for stock, 1:1, and 1:3 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Arista Edu Ultra 200, I am satisfied with F76+ (also sold as Arista Premium Film Developer) at 1:9 dilution for 7:30 @ 20c.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, Arista .EDU Ultra films are rebranded Fomapan (based on everything I've been able to find relative to times, grain structure analysis, antihalation dye characteristics, and cost).

You should therefore be able to use [this page](https://darkroom-solutions.com/cdc/120/Foma%20Fomapan%20200%20Creative/Clayton%20F76%20Plus/200%7C24%C2%B0/1p9/20%20%C2%B0C%20%7C%2068%20%C2%B0F/30%20Seconds) to find times for your .EDU Ultra 200 by using the times listed for Fomapan Creative 200.